# Reduce values duplication in Insert in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to improve a T-SQL procedure that has been written by a former developer, as you can see it contains quite a big amount of Null:

```
    INSERT INTO #titles
    VALUES (
        NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,'ABDABCABSBD'
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
        ,NULL
```

I don't want to change data that are inserted in the table #title (it is necessary).
What I need to do is storing a certain amount of data (for example here, a multiple number of Null in @storing15Null), in order to use directly this variable instead of copying 15 times Null each time the table #title is defined.

```
IF @Group = 11
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #titles
    VALUES (
                @storing15Null
                ,'ZZZZZZ'
                ,'PPPPP'
                @storing10Null)
END

ELSE IF @Group = 17
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #titles
    VALUES (
                @storing15Null
                ,'ABCABCABC'
                @storing15Null)
 END
```

For example using a variable or whatever thing that allows me to store a specific amount of items that will go to VALUES.

Comment: Are you looking for a count of the number of instances of `NULL` to go into `#titles`?

Comment: Reposting an [exact copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67057934/how-to-avoid-duplications-in-t-sql) of a prior question is frowned upon here you know; it wastes the time of the users you are asking for help from as new people trying to help you can't benefit from reading the comments and answers you deleted along with the question.

Comment: As for your question, I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve here? What's wrong with inserting `NULL` 15 times, if you need 15 `NULL` values?

Comment: @Larnu I don't know what you have against me, you said that at this point I should rewrite and post a whole new question. Thing that I did, I rewrote the whole question. I go to stackoverflow when I need help or when I can help someone. Any other neutral moderator could attest that my question is not even 20% similar in term of content compared to the one I deleted.

Comment: *"I don't know what you have against me"* nothing, I hjave clearly been trying to help you here, but you keep moving the goal posts and/or hiding information from those trying to help you (by deleting and reposting the question). Help us help you...

Comment: *"you said that at this point I should rewrite and post a whole new question"* I never said repost it, I said rewrite it; there is an [edit] feature.

Comment: @Larnu What is wrong is that as I stated in the question (" each time the table #title is defined."), the table #title is defined about 20 times in the procedure (depending conditions), and what I insert within this table is quite similar most of the time, so I want to avoid duplication on similar parts within VALUES(...).

Comment: *"the table #title is defined at about 20 times in the procedure"* That doesn't sound right. If you try to create an table (temporary or not) more than once in a procedure (or more specifically in a batch) the parser will generate an error. That will happen even if only one of those `CREATE` statements can be reached, or if explicitly `DROP` said table prior to each `CREATE`. You can't be defining the table 20 times in the procedure; the procedure would fail to compile.

Comment: Though you *could* define the same object multiple times if you used deferred scopes; which could explain why you previously tagged dynamic SQL. Are you, perhaps using `sys.sp_executesql` within you procedure to create the object within the scope of the deferred statement?

Comment: @Larnu It's defined depending on conditions (aka Else if), which means that it is actually defined only 1 time but for each table #title inside a Else if, it goes with different values inserted inside it. (excuse my poor english).

Comment: Like I said, that won't work, @stbr . `IF @a = 1 CREATE TABLE #T (I int); ELSE CREATE TABLE #T (d decimal);` would generate an error stating *"There is already an object named '#T' in the database."* it doesn't matter that it's impossible for bopth `CREATE` statements to be run; the parser isn't that clever.

Comment: @Larnu I got what made the question unclear, I edited the last coding part.

Comment: That doesn't clarify what you are asking still though. If you want 15 rows with the value `NULL` you need to insert 15 rows, with the value `NULL`. What's wrong with doing that? Is your code not working as you expect? If so, what isn't working correctly, what is the code, and what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: @Larnu It does work as I expect, I was just trying to find a way to avoid long and redundant code. Since I haven't found it anywhere, I asked for it, but apparently there is no way to do it ? Would have made it easier to maintain as well, if one of the Null would need to have another value in the future, I could have simply updated one place instead of all of them

Comment: Objects can't "spring into existence" with data, @stbr , no. The only exception to that, sort of, is the `INTO` clause, which both creates and the object (based on the definition of the result set's data), and then inserts the result set into said object. If you are creating a table (be that  permanent, temporary, variable or even type) you need to explicitly define and `INSERT` the data separately to the creation/declaration.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the detailed explanations, really helping.

Comment: `INSERT INTO #titles VALUES(...` This seems to be related to your obscure issue. The first query you posted inserts a single row (as best one can determine from a fragment of a sql statement). It demonstrates a laziness on both the part of the original coder and you. Stop the laziness. Supply a column list and you only need to write "NULL" once in the values clause.

Comment: @SMor It will always insert a single row, that contains for each column the title that is displayed in the client on top of each column of the grid

Comment: If you define the table ONCE and then within each IF ELSE block, then provide an explicit column list for your insert, then you don't need all the NULLs. Not sure why no one is bothered by the lack of the explicit column list in the INSERT statements, that's a requirement everywhere I've ever worked from a standards prospective.

Comment: You don't need to even add columns which are `NULL`, you could leave them out of the `INSERT` completely. So if you specify the column names (**which you should anyway**) you can do `INSERT INTO #titles (col16, col17) VALUES ('ZZZZZZ', 'PPPPP')`

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks for the suggestion, it indeed makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any column which has a default does not need to be specified at all. Since nullable columns have a default of `NULL`, you can simply leave them off the `INSERT` statement.

For this you need to specify the column names explicitly, you should always do this as columns can be reordered:

```sql
INSERT INTO #titles
   (col16, col17)
VALUES
   ('ZZZZZZ', 'PPPPP');
```